# SignalR(v2.2.0) Client.Group() not working for IOS client

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, swift, signalr

I am working on SignalR(v2.2.0) chat with IOS client using [SwiftR](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR). Everything is working fine IOS client as well as web client(Asp.net) is able to do chat using:

**Client:**

```
var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
 $("#btnStartChat").click(function () {

            var name = $("#txtNickName").val();//UserName
            var userId = $("#txtUserId").val();
            var room = $("#txtRoomId").val();
            if (name.length > 0) {
                chatHub.server.joinRoom(userId, room, name).done(function () {
                    chatHub.server.connect(userId, room, name);
                });
            }
            else {
                alert("Please enter name");
            }

        });
  chatHub.client.messageReceived = function (userName, message) {

            AddMessage(userName, message);
            $("#istyping").html('');
        };
 function AddMessage(userName, message) {
        $('#divChatWindow').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' + userName + '</span>: ' + message + '</div>');

        var height = $('#divChatWindow')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('#divChatWindow').scrollTop(height);
    }
   // On New User Connected
        chatHub.client.onNewUserConnected = function (id, name) {
            // alert('first time add');
            AddUser(chatHub, id, name);
        };
```

**Server:**

```
 public async Task JoinRoom(string user_Id, string room_Id, string user_Name)
    {
        //Add user in database for room
        AddLoginUser(room_Id, this.Context.ConnectionId, user_Id);

        await this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, room_Id);
    }


    public void Connect(string user_Id, string room_Id, string user_Name)
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;
        Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, user_Name, GetRoomUser(room_Id), GetRoomMessage(room_Id));

        // send to all in group to update user list
        Clients.OthersInGroup(room_Id).onNewUserConnected(id, user_Name);
    }



 public void SendMessageToAll(string user_Name, string message, string room_Id, string user_Id)
    {
        // store messages in db
        // SaveRoomMessage(user_Id, message, room_Id);

        // Broad cast message
        Clients.All.messageReceived(user_Name, message);
        //Clients.Group(room_Id).messageReceived(user_Name, message);
    }
```

**Problem:**

In the above method if am changing the

```
 Clients.All.messageReceived(user_Name, message);
```

to

```
 Clients.Group(room_Id).messageReceived(user_Name, message);
```

IOS Client not able to receive message even IOS client is able to send message to web client. Here web client are able to send and receive messages between each other without any problem.

I searched a lot regarding this on web but didn't find out any proper ans to this. If still need any more info then please let me know i will try to provide as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you adding your clients to groups ? Something like `await this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, room_Id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing something like that to add your clients to your groups?

Server :

```
public async Task JoinRoom(string room_id)
{
    await this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, room_id);
}

public async Task UnJoinRoom(string room_id)
{
    await this.Groups.Remove(this.Context.ConnectionId, room_id);
}
```

Client :

**js**:

```
var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
chatHub.server.joinRoom('roomId')
```

**swift** :

```
chatHub.invoke("joinRoom", arguments: ["room_id"])
```

After if you call

```
Clients.Group('room_Id').messageReceived(user_Name, message);
```

it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i will try this and let you soon as soon as possible.

Comment: Roger i had updated my question as per your suggestions and everything working fine IOS client able to send/receive messages. But login user list on web client not updated if user added in IOS on the other hand everything working fine in Web.

Comment: What is the login user list? How are you updating this list ? (I mean on the client side)

Comment: please check update for onNewUserConnected  method to update client list.

Comment: You should add some logs when the ios client launch the connect function (server side). In the client you can enable logging with `$connection.logging = true;`. It ll help you to find the issue

Comment: for time being the main problem is solved. Thanks for your solution.